# Are there any special audio settings needed to make Twilio VOIP on iOS work?

Tags: ios, voip, twilio

I'm trying to set up a Twilio VOIP Client on iOS and have been able to make all of the examples connect to the example server. However when I run in the simulator or on device, I'm not able to hear any audio from the VOIP call. Are there any special audio settings needed? I've already tried:

```
UInt32 route = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(route), &route);
```

but had no luck. I've also set `audio` and `voip` for `UIBackgroundModes`. Is there anything else I should be setting up?

Comment: have you tried emailing customer support? they may be able to help. try help@twilio.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Twilio's trial account? If you followed their documentation and there are still problems with the client VOIP calls, then it might be worth a shot to upgrade. Twilio has been having problems with their free trial accounts so I'd try the update first.

Comment: Upgrading to a paid account did the trick, no other changes necessary. Thanks!

Comment: @wesley could you please provide links for your ans?